# Find an unitary operator $U$ , on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $(U - I)$ is not compact.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I have tried $U=iI$ but $U^\ast=iI$ and $UU^\ast=(-1)I$ which is not $I$ so $U$ is not unitary.
Could you please give me one right example. Thanks.

Comment: Your computation of $U^\ast$ is incorrect. Your example does work.

Comment: I suspect left shift on $\ell_2(\Bbb Z)$ would work.

Comment: Thank you PhoemueX, Robert, Jose and David.